# Hide Div When Window X Position is past 1700px - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a single page horizontal scrolling site that is 10,000 px wide and have a fixed position div that I only want to show with-in the first 1700 px of my site. So in other words when the windows x position is at 1700 px or greater I want the div to hide. How can I do this with jQuery? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(window).scroll( function() {
        if ($(window).scrollLeft() > 1700)
            $('#targetDiv').hide();
        else
            $('#targetDiv').show();
    } );
} );
```